# Mockito dateformat returning incorrect month; assertEquals fails

Tags: java, exception, junit, mockito, simpledateformat

I am trying to mock DateFormat using mockito. I just want the current month to be displayed. In my Junit test, I'm doing the following in my Junit test :

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    reportQueryParams = ReportQueryParams.builder()
        .id("07")
        .build();
}

@Test
public void tabSerializerTest() {
    DateFormat formatter = Mockito.mock(SimpleDateFormat.class);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("July");
    Mockito.when(formatter.format(Mockito.any(Date.class), Mockito.any(StringBuffer.class),
        Mockito.any(FieldPosition.class))).thenReturn(stringBuffer);

    MetricsSerializer metricsSerializer = new MetricsSerializer();
    String tabSeparated = metricsSerializer.serializeMetrics(reportQueryParams);
    String expected = new StringBuilder().append("074")
        .append("\t")
        .append("July")
        .toString();
    assertEquals(expected, tabSeparated);
}
```

The function which I am testing:

```
public String serializeMetrics(final ReportQueryParams reportQueryParams) {
    stringJoiner = new StringJoiner("\t");
    addValueFromString(reportQueryParams.getId());
    addValueFromString(getCurrentMonth());
    return stringJoiner.toString();
}

private String getCurrentMonth() {
    DateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM");
    return monthFormat.format(new Date());
}


private void addValueFromString(final String value) {
    stringJoiner.add(value);
}
```

My ReportQueryParams class:

```
  public class ReportQueryParams {
        private String id;
    }
```

I am getting "August" as the month returned from the function. Hence, the assertEquals is failing. How can I fix this?

Comment: change the argument matcher, also you would need to refactor the code to inject the class as you are manually creating the instance.

Comment: How? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: You would need to provide more details about what is being tested and how you are testing it in a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am just getting the current month using the "getCurrentMonth()" function. In the test, I'm trying to mock this behavior and providing the month.

Comment: Sorry, but you should first read the documentation of the tool you intend to use. Mocking is complicated stuff. You dont learn that by trial and error. You start with a good tutorial, and you work that top to bottom. `Mockito.when(formatter.format(new Date()))` is wrong, you need something like `Mockito.when(formatter.format(any()))` (where any is that argument matcher)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that at no point does the mock end up in the class under test so the arranged behavior is not being invoked.

That is because you are creating the formatter withing the method under test

```
DateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM");
```

tightly coupling the class to the dependency, which makes testing difficult but not impossible.

Unfortunately PowerMockito allows things like this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = mock(SimpleDateFormat.class); 
when(formatter.format(any(Date.class)).thenReturn("July");
PowerMockito.whenNew(SimpleDateFormat.class).withArguments(anyString()).thenReturn(formatter);

//...Do not forget to include @PrepareForTest(SimpleDateFormat.class) on the test class
```

When ideally what you should be doing is refactoring the class to expose any explicit dependencies, either via construct or method arguments, that can injected into the subject under test.

```
public interface MonthProvider {
    private String getCurrentMonth();
}

public class DefaultMonthProvider implements MonthProvider {
    DateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM");

    public String getCurrentMonth() {            
        return monthFormat.format(new Date());
    }
}

public class MetricsSerializer {

    MonthProvider provider;
    public MetricsSerializer(MonthProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public String serializeMetrics(final ReportQueryParams reportQueryParams) {
        stringJoiner = new StringJoiner("\t");
        addValueFromString(reportQueryParams.getId());
        addValueFromString(provider.getCurrentMonth());
        return stringJoiner.toString();
    }

    private void addValueFromString(final String value) {
        stringJoiner.add(value);
    }
}
```

that can be injected into the subject under test.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    reportQueryParams = ReportQueryParams.builder()
        .id("07")
        .build();
}

@Test
public void tabSerializerTest() {
    //Arrange
    MonthProvider privider = Mockito.mock(MonthProvider.class);
    Mockito.when(provider.getCurrentMonth()).thenReturn("July");    
    MetricsSerializer metricsSerializer = new MetricsSerializer(provider);
    String expected = new StringBuilder().append("07")
        .append("\t")
        .append("July")
        .toString();

    //Act
    String actual = metricsSerializer.serializeMetrics(reportQueryParams);

    //Assert        
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way this could be done without using PowerMockito?

Comment: @TeeJay Not without refactoring the formatter out of the subject class so that a mock can be injected.

Comment: The formatter should be removed out of the class or the method "getCurrentMonth()"?

Comment: @TeeJay `getCurrentMonth` would be the better choice to abstract out of the subject class as the `SimpleDateFormat` is more of an implementation concern

Comment: I tried  MetricsSerializer mockMonth = mock(MetricsSerializer.class);
        when(mockMonth.getCurrentMonth()).thenReturn("July"); but that gives August as well.

Comment: @TeeJay review my updated answer. You are trying to mock the wrong thing